# meteor 1.6 cannot add angular2-compilers

Tags: meteor, upgrade, angular-meteor

On a fresh install of Meteor 1.6, I am trying to add the angular2-compilers package to a new meteor app i.e.

```
meteor create v16app
cd v16app
meteor add angular2-compilers
```

Which fails as follows;

```
 => Errors while adding packages: 

While loading package angular2-compilers@0.6.6:
error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c 
C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd rebuild --update-binary
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.8.0/win32-x64-57_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found
```

I have only noticed this problem whilst upgrading from 1.5.2.2.

How do I resolve this?  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We released a new version of the compilers.
Now, like Angular, they are just `angular-compilers` instead of `angular2-compilers`.

It now works way better and supports all the nice things from Angular like AOT compilation, Angular Universal and SSR and lazy loading.

Check out a couple of example apps here - https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/tree/master/examples/MeteorCLI

Comment: Great Thanks.  I've built that project and it works (with a little prodding on Windows).  But I am a little confused.  I resolved my issue above by removing angular2-compilers and adding in barbatus:typescript on the server.   I use Angular Cli + Meteor Client Bundler in the client and it all works fine without angular-compilers package on the server.  So, I am confused as to why I need angular-compilers at all now?

Comment: Ohh I thought you are using the Meteor CLI also on the client. if not, then there is no reason for you to use `angular-compilers`